# Binomial coefficients with summation

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> $$\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{24} \binom{100}{4r}\binom{100}{4r+2}}{\sum_{r=1}^{25}\binom{200}{8r-6}}$$

The numerator is fine by multiplying 2 sequences we can easily get it but the denominator is taking a long time to be figured out using 8th roots of unity .  I am searching for an alternate method to figure out the denominator .Please help

Comment: Can you edit the first line? It's a bit hard to understand as currently written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $$D:= \sum_{r=1}^{25}\binom{200}{8r-6} = \sum_{r=0}^{24}\binom{200}{8r+2}$$
Then first note that by reindexing and using $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$, we have
$$\sum_{r=0}^{24}\binom{200}{8r+2} = \sum_{r=0}^{24}\binom{200}{8(24-r)+2} = \sum_{r=0}^{24} \binom{200}{200-(8(24-r)+2)} = \sum_{r=0}^{24}\binom{200}{8r+6}$$

In particular, we note
$$2^{199} = \sum_{k=0}^{100}\binom{200}{2r} = 2D+\sum_{r=0}^{50}\binom{200}{4r},$$
so
$$\begin{align*}D &= 2^{198}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{r=0}^{50}\binom{200}{4r} \\&= 2^{198}-\frac{1}{8}(2^{200}+(1+i)^{200}+(1-i)^{200}) \\ &= 2^{197}-2^{98}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Yes but we need to find the ratio of N/D. Numerator comes out to be 200C98 so how can we find the ratio here. I guess we need to rearrange somehow. The answer given is 1 .

Comment: @Saddy No matter how I interpret your question, I can't get the answer to be 1.  Do you want to double-check the entire problem?  Alternatively, if this is from a textbook, which book and problem is it?

Comment: Yes it's a question by our school math teacher as a part of a worksheet. In my answersheet I had shown all the steps but they didn't give me full marks because I couldn't show the answer to be 1.

Comment: Could you please explain how could you get the 5th line where you found an equation for denominator?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about $$\sum_{r=0}^{50}\binom{200}{4r} = \frac{1}{4}(2^{200} + (1+i)^{200} + (1-i)^{200}),$$ it just comes from adding $$(1+x)^{200} = \sum_{k=0}^{200}\binom{200}{k}x^k$$ for $x=1, -1, i, -i$ and noting that $$1^k + (-1)^k + i^k + (-i)^k = \begin{cases}4 & \text{ if } 4 \mid k \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation